# Jquery show/hide not at all working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is the link to my website.
[Website](https://ifixandrepair.com/finalUpGrade/)
I have applied jquery for hide and show menu items in **LOCATIONS** menu as u can see in website.
It is not at all working on mobile devices. By default the list items are hide using CSS.
I think the event.preventDefault(); is not working fine as it is reloading the page.
here is my

JS:

```
$("li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group > a").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.dropdown-mega.level2').hide();
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
        $(this).closest('.parent').find('.dropdown-mega.level2').show();
});
```

I think the event.preventDefault(); is not working fine as it is reloading the page.

Comment: In which file you've your js code? file name ?

Comment: @ShehrozAhmed Iam using opencart and i have added my code in common.js inside function init when the document ready function is run

Comment: The problem is your event is not binding on "a" tag when the screen size gets small, let me check the issue :)

Comment: @ShehrozAhmed ok please update

Comment: @ShehrozAhmed what i see in mobile url is that it goes to href="#" which means that eventdefault is not working on mobile

Comment: 1st Problem : You've two ids named #li_menu169
2nd Problem : You've loading scripts using async attribute in the scripts. remove async attribute from this common.js script and try again :)

Comment: Couldnt get u at all. how will i remove async attribute from this common.js

Comment: Talking about this one. http://prntscr.com/8qdz3f
Also change $("#li_menu169 li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group > a") to $("li.parent.dropdown-submenu.mega-group > a")

Comment: @ShehrozAhmed iam unable to remove this async  because its not present in my common.js plus in header where i include it its not added to this file

Comment: go to header and remove o_O what's the issue in removing this?

Comment: ist not present in header :) thats the issue

Comment: @ShehrozAhmed i removed the async from my header an tried again but it didnt hepl. because it still is going to href="#" which means eventdefault() not working

Answer (score 0):

Add this too  `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` before the `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: I have added it but its still not working. i see it reloading page with href="#"

Answer (score 0):

try adding `return false;` after `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: i did as u said.. it stopped everything i.e. i was even unable to click a link. i added return false; at the end it was ok again but still failing on mobile

Comment: try adding return false at the end.. or instead of href="#" add href="javascript:;"

Comment: add href="javascript:;" with this syntax?

Comment: yes.. <a href="javascript:;"></a> and NOT <a href="#"></a> hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use some plugin to make it work in mobile device. You can try hammer.js to achieve this. This plugin provides many touch events.

http://hammerjs.github.io/

Comment: my simple problem is that event.preventDefault(); is not working in mobile device. just for this sake its odd to shift to a plugin to achieve it. please help me on what i am using currently.

Comment: Just a suggestion :- try to use stopPropagation() also with prevent default.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has struggled with it as me, **can be a browser cache**. Try to clean it (or test in an incognito window).

Can be the case if you are developing that page and testing on the device at the same time. For some reason, seems the mobile browsers don't download javascript file for every refresh.

Hope that helps.